# Hide a feature in Site Collection Administration => Features area

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation, powershell, feature, feature-activation

I have a feature with webparts that needs to be activated using powershell.  I need a way to either hide the feature on the Site Collection Administration => Features (under Site Settings) or to prevent activation from the Site Settings.  Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why does it have to be activated via PowerShell? Arguments?

Comment: Don't give your user site collection admin rights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are the creator of the feature, simply set the [`Hidden` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms436075.aspx) to TRUE in the feature.xml file.  That will make it so the feature cannot be enabled/disabled through the UI but can still be controlled through powershell